# Sci Fi movie about space battle against aliens that I watched on a VCR

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think it started out with three space ships in space crossing a asteroid field. One battle ship on each side of what I think they were protecting. Then a guy space walked a "space mine" onto a side of an asteroid and when the asteroid made a 180 it blew up an alien spaceship.

It also had a Space station around earth, they went into how hard it was to build it and all the mistakes they made to make it. It looked like it had three cylinders attached together, the middle one going in a opposite direction. Made that gravity effect.

Toward the end of it the aliens had this web-like ship, very big and spread out covered in a dark cloud when it was on its way to blow up Earth. The humans had all their ships ready to defend and also made these two ships that the aliens didn't want to blow up because they had a different configuration. But a traitor gave the blueprints to the aliens so that he could survive. Then one of the two ships rammed into to web-like thing because they could only shoot ones and they shot at the wrong "Web connection". Aliens ran because there web-like thing blew up, but not before they poisoned the Earth's air. Then the last ship of the two went onto a quest to find a cure.

Comment: Are you sure it's not *Babylon 5: A Call to Arms (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_A_Call_to_Arms)? The description isn't completely there, but it sounds very similar. Like you just have one or two details slightly off. It was a television movie involving a web-like ship, a spinning space station in three parts - the titular *Babylon 5* - though not over Earth, a traitor who gave information on the two prototype ships to the enemy, a space-dock among asteroids, rather than an asteroid mine, and various other similarities.

Comment: The "space mine" in the asteroid field was from a different film, "Babylon 5: The Beginning", which was all about the Earth-Minbari War.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_In_the_Beginning

Answer (score 8):

As the comments from James and Will state, your question sounds very much like a melding of two separate Babylon 5 TV movies.  They would have been from the right time period for VCR viewing (90's).

[A Call To Arms](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146455/) was essentially the finale for the TV series and dealt with the Shadow Planet Killer (a giant web like ship concealed in a cloud used to obliterate the surface of planets).  The Interstellar Alliance had two brand new, powerful warships based partly on Vorlon technology.  They use these to try and stop it.  The first ship fires its gun but fails to hit the target and is disabled by temporary power loss.  The second ship decides to ram the control module of the planet killer and thus destroys it.  It ends with some of the alien fleet deploying a plague across the Earth and fleeing.

[In The Beginning](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120711/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) was a prequel to the TV series made to give some background and discusses the Earth/Minbari war.  This one contains the scene where Earth ships mine an asteroid field with nukes and are able to use this to destroy the Minbari flag ship.

Both movies were made in between the end of the original [Babylon 5](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120711/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) TV series and the beginning of the short lived followup series, [Crusade](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0149437/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), which lasted only 1 season.  Crusade followed up on the end of the A Call To Arms movie and featured the surviving battleship and its quest to find a cure for the plague left on Earth at the end of the movie.

Comment: *In the Beginning* was released between Season 4 and Season 5 of *Babylon 5*, not between the end of the series and the start of *Crusade*.

Comment: Whoops, yep, you're right.  Got my timeline off a little.